# Is there anyway to let cursorline take care of the visual tabs generated by 'breakindent'?

Tags: wrapping, cursorline

[image: example]

now the cursorline leaves a hideous gap between the number column and the wrapped text, is there any way or trick to make the cursorline take care of the whole part of the wrapped line including the visual tabs generated by `'breakindent'`?

Comment: no not possible

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as of today. The reason most likely is, that the non-highlighted indented part is actually only a representation and does not really exist in the file. I am not sure it makes sense, to color that for the cursorline.

For reference, this question has made it to a Vim Ticket: [#3355](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3355)